# Spring Boot Docker Maven Plugin with module dependencies

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-maven-plugin

I am using docker-maven-plugin(Spotify) to build my docker images generated by Dockerfile in my Spring Boot project. If the project has no any module dependency it works well. 
But if a module is dependent to another like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
    <artifactId>helper</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run

./mvnw install dockerfile:build

I got

> Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   com.mysite:web:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not
>   be resolved: com.mysite:helper:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

How can I solve this?

Comment: I am trying to build web module and containerize it. It needs helper module to run

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin to accomplish this.

1) Create a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

COPY build/libs/yourapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /application.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/application.jar"]
```

2) Create a shell script, or use a simple `Makefile` to do the building:

```
VERSION ?= $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)
APP     ?= k8specs-platform-api
IMAGE   ?= gcr.io/matthewdavis-devops/$(APP):$(VERSION)

.PHONY: build

all: build push

build:

    ./gradlew bootJar
    docker build -t $(IMAGE) .

run:

    docker run -p 8080:8080 $(IMAGE)

push:

    docker push $(IMAGE)
```

3) Just run `make all` and profit!

No need for a silly plugin ;)